# How to create 6 frieze patterns in Python

Tags: python, python-turtle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffyT8.png)

I need to be able to create a frieze pattern of six shapes. The link provides a visual of the shape and the size it needs to be.

```py
from turtle import *

number_of_shapes = 6

# Draw six basic elements

for shape in range (number_of_shapes):
       # Draw a basic element

       for section in range(8):
              forward(30)
              right(110)
              forward(30)
              left(20)
              forward(30)
              right(110)
              forward(30)
              left(20)
              forward(30)
              right(110)
              forward(30)
              left(20)
              forward(20)
              right(110)
              forward(30)
```

this code creates a different shape to the pattern I need which I found quite funny.

Comment: You need to change with which arguments `left` and `right` are called. And you probably need to do something between each shape to move to a new position.

Comment: Is your struggle to draw one of those stars or 6 at once?

Comment: I'm struggling to draw all 6 at once.

Comment: So if you change `number_of_shapes` from 6 to 1, everything is correct?

Comment: No. My entire code is wrong and I don't know how to change it to create 6 stars with 100 unit space between each one.

Comment: So your first step should be to draw 1 star.

Comment: You need to think of yourself walking along the line and how much of an angle you need to turn from going straight ahead rather than just plugging in the angles of the figure.  And you need to think about moving to get the figures not all on top of each other.

Comment: Your math isn't mathing. Start with `turtle.right(80)` so you are pointing in the right direction to start. Then repeat the following for times to build each arm of the star: walk 30 steps, turn left 70 degrees, walk 30 steps, turn right 160 degrees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just used the angles specified in the diagram, without wondering how `turtle` will interpret them.

The key is to think of `180` minus the stated angle.

Plus one run through the turns and forwards creates one star all on its own.

Your code should have been more like this:

```py
from turtle import *

number_of_shapes = 6

LEFT=180-110
RIGHT=180-20
# Draw six basic elements
penup()
left(180)
forward(100*number_of_shapes // 2)
right(180)
for shape in range (number_of_shapes):
       # Draw a basic element
      left(10) 
      pendown()
      forward(30)
      left(LEFT)
      forward(30)
      right(RIGHT)
      forward(30)
      left(LEFT)
      forward(30)
      right(RIGHT)
      forward(30)
      left(LEFT)
      forward(30)
      right(RIGHT)
      forward(30)
      left(LEFT)
      forward(30)
      right(RIGHT)
      right(10)
      penup()
      forward(100)
```

Comment: Wow OK thank you very much. I shall try that code and see what happens.

Comment: OMG it works!! I can't thank you enough because I have been struggling with this code for the past few days and my assignment deadline is this coming Thursday. Thank you thank you, you don't know how much this means to me...........i'm in tears.

Comment: Its great to be of service, but have you learned what I did to make it work? Could you write code for a different shape?

Comment: Absolutely! I can create lots of basic shapes and stairs too. I'm a complete amateur at python and programming full stop and to receive help like you've offered me is truly amazing. Thank you again.